# How to tell to buildout to use setup.py from subdirectory?

Tags: python, odoo, buildout

I'm trying to install aeroolib with buildout. Unfortunately when I get module from bzr there is one more level, so setup.py is not inside aeroolib, but inside aeroolib/aeroolib. How can I tell buildout to search for setup.py inside subdirectory?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `develop` flag in the `buildout` section. Something like:

```
[buildout]
...
develop = aeroolib/aeroolib
```